# Why sum of two MaxIntegers returns -2?

Tags: java, integer

I'm playing with some simple java code and I found something which I cannot explain to myself. I hope some of you can explain it to me.

I have code like this :

```
public int sum() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

I wrote a test like this:

```
@Test
public void testSum() throws Exception {
    Integer num = myclass.sum();
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

So I'm expecting this to throw some type of exception. But the test prints -2.

Currently my jdk is 1.8.0x60.

Best regards,
Petar

Comment: Why did you expect an exception?

Comment: take a look at [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) plus [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Because that is exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Use `return Math.addExact(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);` to get the exception you expected. I agree that the expectation is reasonable, but standard Java math doesn’t give you that.